# Entity Framework check for uniqueness before insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I have an `Invoice` type like:

```
public class Invoice : IEntity, IValidatableObject
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invoice Number is a required field.")]
        [Display(Name = "Invoice Number:")]
        public virtual string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invoice Date is a required field.")]
        [Display(Name = "Invoice Date:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Organisation is a required field.")]
        [Display(Name = "Organisation:")]
        public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Region is a required field.")]
        [Display(Name = "Region:")]
        public virtual int? AreaId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Total (Exc. GST) is a required field.")]
        [Display(Name = "Total (Exc. GST):")]
        public decimal? TotalExcludingGst { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Total (Inc. GST) is a required field.")]
        [Display(Name = "Total (Inc. GST):")]
        public decimal? TotalIncludingGst { get; set; }
        public virtual string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
        public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }

        #region IValidatableObject Members

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if ((TotalExcludingGst + (TotalExcludingGst * .15m)) != TotalIncludingGst) {
                yield return new ValidationResult("The total (exc. Gst) + Gst does not equal the total (inc. Gst).");
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

What I want to do is make sure on insert update that the combination of `Organsation` and `InvoiceNumber` is unique.

I'm considering something like:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                var repository = new Repository<Invoice>();

                if(!repositoy.CheckUnique(Id)) {
                    yield return new ValidationResult("The combination of Organisation and Invoice number is already in use");
                }
            }
```

Is this bad practise? To be instantiating the repository inside the model?

Is there a better way?

Comment: what's wrong with capturing the exception and processing it then?  That way you're only making extra calls to the database when you need to.

Comment: What do you want the answer to your question to be? A better way would be checking prior to saving, inside the repository. Or just saving and then handling an exception such as @Jeremy suggested.

Comment: But would this populate the ValidationSummary?

Comment: I agree, add the UIX to the DB, then catch the exception. Because it's not like your making any decisions if the value **isn't** unique, just throwing an error, so it adds no value to check first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not work correctly in a multi user scenario. Because between checking whether an `ID` exists and saving changes another record maybe inserted with that same `ID`.

You can create a `Unique Constraint` on your table. This is the safe way to ensure duplicates are not created.

Current versions of EF does not model/support `Unique Constraint`s. However what you can do is catch the specific exception and check the error message. Then show the errors

```
try
{
    //updation logic
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (System.Data.DataException de)
{
    Exception innerException = de;
    while (innerException.InnerException != null)
    {
        innerException = innerException.InnerException;
    }

    if (innerException.Message.Contains("Unique_constraint_name"))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error Message");
        return;
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error Message");

    return View();
}
```

If you are using ASP.NET Web forms you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777889/on-postback-how-can-i-add-a-error-message-to-validation-summary/777954#777954)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best option. Though, I can see Microsoft changing the message text which would cause it not to work. It would be better if there was some kind of UniqueConstraintException. Your approach will have to do for now.