# Using a validation summary to display label text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have taken over maintenance of a site that makes calls through a WCF service. There is a validation summary that displays in a message box for some validators on the client-side. I also have a label that fires if any exceptions arise from my web service calls. After tweaking the layout, the label sits in an inconvenient spot. I want to know if there is a way to display the label text in the validation summary should the exception fire in the code behind.

Any advice is appreciated.

Example in cs file:

```
bool ResultUserExistence = register.CheckUniquenessUserID(txtUserId.Text);

if (ResultUniquenessEmail == null)
{
    continue through code...
}

else
{
    lblException.Text = "Please choose a different user name. The current user name is already registered.";
}
```

Validation Summary:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSummary"
                    runat="server"
                    HeaderText="Please correct the following error(s):"
                    DisplayMode="List"
                    ForeColor="#FF9999"
                    ShowMessageBox="True"
                    ShowSummary="False" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As notied in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777889/on-postback-how-can-i-add-a-error-message-to-validation-summary) you could create a custom validator, and set the message on that, which will make the message show up in your validation summary.

```
bool ResultUserExistence = register.CheckUniquenessUserID(txtUserId.Text);

if (ResultUniquenessEmail == null)
{
    continue through code...
}

else
{
    var err As new CustomValidator()
    err.ValidationGroup = "UserUniqueness";
    err.IsValid = False;
    err.ErrorMessage = "Please choose a different user name. The current user name is already registered.";
    Page.Validators.Add(err);    

}
```

Ideally this would be factored out into a method for reusability.