# Show error message of a dynamically added validator in Validation Summary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I extended the  textbox class as follows to act as a DateTextBox and validate the field format:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Myapplication.App_Code
{
    public class DateTextBox  : TextBox
    {
        private RegularExpressionValidator regexval;
        public string InvalidDate="Incorrect date format, must be dd/mm/yyyy";
        public string ClientScript = "true";

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {

            regexval = new RegularExpressionValidator();
            regexval.ControlToValidate = this.ID;
            regexval.ErrorMessage ="'"+this.Text+"'"+ this.InvalidDate;
            regexval.EnableClientScript = (this.ClientScript.ToLower() != "false");
            regexval.ValidationExpression = "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](19|20)\\d\\d$";
            //regexval.Text = "*Incorrect date format";
            regexval.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            regexval.Display = ValidatorDisplay.None;
            Controls.Add(regexval);

            base.OnInit(e);
        }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            Attributes.Add("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(writer);
            regexval.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

In my aspx, I have this datetextbox as well several other controls that have the out-of-the-box required field validators.

Here's my aspx:

```
<td>
     <RE:LabelExtended runat="server" ID="lblDateOfBirth" Text="Birth Date" Required="True">
      </RE:LabelExtended>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqValDateOfBirth" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateOfBirth"  ErrorMessage="Please enter Date of Birth" ForeColor="Red" Display="None"  ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 </td>
 <td>
          <RE:DateTextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateOfBirth" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></RE:DateTextBox>
  </td>

 <td>
     <asp:ValidationSummary ID="Tab1ValidationSummary" runat="server" ShowSummary="true" ForeColor="Red" Enabled="true"   />

   </td>
```

My problem is that the regular expression validator in my DateTextBox control doesn't show its error message in the validation summary along the other controls.
Any idea how to do that ?

EDIT:

I tried giving all controls on the page a validation group and giving the same group to the regular expression in the control and this made the error message appear as required, but i can't fix the validation group in my control since i got several pages that use this control.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777889/on-postback-how-can-i-add-a-error-message-to-validation-summary):

I added `Page.Validators.Add(regexval);` to the control and it worked well without validation groups