# How to show Catch block exceptions in Validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch, validationsummary

I have a try and catch block for sending multiple emails. Everytime a exception in email address occurs then in Catch block it is set as text to multiline textbox. But I am having problem showing large data.

the current code is:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   txtexception.Text = txtexception.Text + "\n" + ex.Message;                   
}
```

Note: I am testing it on data having 5 incorrect email addresses. So there are 5 exception messages to display.

So, I am now thinking of displaying error messages in `validation summary control`. Is there any way to do that from code behind(button click).

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Use a `CustomValidator` to set custom error message from `catch` block. You can create custom validator in markup, or add it dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, will search for that! If you can provide link to any example that would be great! thanks again

Comment: You can see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777889/on-postback-how-can-i-add-a-error-message-to-validation-summary). The implementation depends on which event that `catch` block belongs to.

Comment: ok will look, Thanks